# Swift: Change TableViewCell Height Dynamically and change WebView Height Dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiwebview

I have a `TableViewController`, inside the `TableViewCell`, I have a `UIWebView`. I want the `UIWebView` to display some content from the internet, but I don't want the scroll effect, I want the `WebView` to have a dynamic height based on the length of the content. In addition, I want the `TableViewCell` to be able to adjust its cell height dynamically based on the dynamic height of `WebView`. Is this possible?

This is how I implemented my `TableViewController`:

```
class DetailTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var passPost: Posts = Posts()
var author: Author = Author()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getAuthor()

}
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("detailCell")

let postImageUrlString = passPost.postThumbnailUrlString
        let postImageUrl = NSURL(string: postImageUrlString)
        let size = CGSize(width: 414.0, height:212.0 )
        let filter = AspectScaledToFillSizeFilter(size: size)
        (cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView).af_setImageWithURL(postImageUrl!, filter: filter)

        //Set Author Avatar

        let authorAvatarUrlString = author.authorAvatarUrlString
        let authorAvatarUrl = NSURL(string: authorAvatarUrlString)

        //Mark - Give Author Avatar a Round Corner

        let filter2 = AspectScaledToFillSizeWithRoundedCornersFilter(size: (cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView).frame.size, radius: 20.0)

        (cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView).af_setImageWithURL(authorAvatarUrl!, filter: filter2)


        //Set Post Title and Content and so on

        (cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(4) as! UILabel).text = passPost.postTitle
        (cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(6) as! UIWebView).loadHTMLString("\(passPost.postContent)", baseURL: nil)
```

for the `heightForCellAtIndexPath` I did

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! tableViewCell
    tableView.rowHeight = cell.theWebView.scrollView.contentSize.height
    return tableView.rowHeight
}
```

This is working fine, except the `WebView` has a scroll effect, and the height is limited due to the limitation of the `TableViewCell`. So, how to achieve what I need?

Comment: Have you tried setting `yourWebView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled` to `false`?

Comment: yes, I tried, by doing that, the WebView cannot be scrolled, however it couldn't display all content since the `TableViewCell` height is not dynamic.

Comment: Can you post your heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate method implementation?

Comment: I didn't set the `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, thats where I am not sure how to implement, thanks if you have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the height of your cell in the `UITableViewDelegate` method 
[tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:)

You would do all your calculations on each individual cell height in this method and return it. If you want to display the `UIWebView` in it's whole without the need to scroll, you should return the height of the UIWebView's scroll view contentView – plus any height for anything else you might want to display in this cell.

Comment: so you mean, for example, if inside the `TableViewCell` I just want to display the whole content of the `WebView`, i need to set the height inside the function `heightForRowAtIndexPath` like maybe this `tableView.rowHeight = theWebView.scrollView.contentSize.height` is this right? thanks

Comment: Kind of. You would implement this method, do your height calculations and `return heightForThisCellIJustCalculated`

Comment: `heightForThisCellJustCalculated` is a value by default or you mean the value I calculated? sorry I am new to swift

Comment: It is the value you would calculate.

Comment: but the content is dynamic, I can't calculate it. I just used this line `tableView.rowHeight = cell.theWebView.scrollView.contentSize.height`, but swift give me an error `missing return in a function expected to return 'CGFloat'`, what else should I return?

Comment: Can you post your heightForRowAt: delegate method now?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps:

1) set leading, trailing, top, bottom constraint 0(zero) from webview to tableviewCell

2) Now no need to call HeightForRow method of tableView.

3) in webview delegate method

```
   func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) 
       {

        var frame = cell.webView.frame
        frame.size.height = 1
        let fittingSize = cell.webView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeZero)
        frame.size = fittingSize

        }
```

4) webview scrollenabled = false

Comment: I put step 3 &4 inside `func cellForRowAthIndexPath`, is that right?

Comment: it just not working. I didn't set the height for the cell, and set the constraints like you said. and `webView.scrollenable` is false. so right now the WebView can not be scrolled, but the it didn't show all the content.

Comment: ok.get it. Now yo have to define that cell in webViewDidFinish method and you have to reload this cell after setting fittingSize and call HEightForRowmethod which return fittingSize. get it?

Comment: sorry, I am new to swift, would you mind edit your answer again? thanks so much.

Comment: its quite long process. I suggest you steps: call webviewDelegate so you can know height of webview,now you have to set height of cell as per height of webview.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121628/discussion-between-leo-guo-and-swift-guru).

Answer (score 0):

You can return, in heightForRowAtIndexPath:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

You also need to have a value setted in estimatedRowHeight, like

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 85.0
```

If you have all the constraints defined correctly in the Storyboard (Or programmatically), you shouldn't get any error.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html

Comment: I tried this before, and it gave me the error `Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead.`